# Best known lower bound for $bb(7)$ after Pavel Kropitz's breakthrough?

Tags: reference-request, turing-machines, big-numbers

Concerning the busy beaver with $6$ states , there recently occured a major breakthrough : Pavel Kropitz has proven $bb(6)>10\uparrow \uparrow 15$.

The old record was just in an "astronomical" level and a machine with $7$ states was derived proving $bb(7)\gg10\uparrow\uparrow 5$.

> What is the best lower bound that can be derived from the new record of $bb(6)$ in a similar way ? Is this bound the best known lower bound for $bb(7)$ ?

Comment: Use `\gg` and `\ll` to obtain $x\gg y$ and $x\ll y$